# Opening a link from postman response in an external browser using script

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm getting `URL` as a response in postman. I want to open that response in the default browser using `script`.  What is the `javascript` to open that `url` in a browser automatically from postman?

Comment: I don't think so that there is provision to write scripts inside postman.

Comment: postman can run test script like tests   ["Successful POST request"] = responseCode.code === 201 || responseCode.code === 202; opening a url i dont think possible

Comment: can we achieve it by using any plugins?

Comment: My use case for wanting to do this is pushing up a 3d secure web page (from a payment gateway sandbox) to test a payment flow.